# Java: Descending to Ascending

Tags: java

I made this with my friend and would like to know if.

How can we change the condition where if someone would let us change it to ascending order?

```
    public class EXP2 {
        public static void main(String args[]){
        int nInputs;
                    int kth;
                            int temporarystorage;
                System.out.print("Number of inputs: ");
                nInputs = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
                int inputs[] = new int[nInputs];
                do{
                    System.out.print("Enter Kth Largest Number: ");
                    kth = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
                }
                while(!(kth>0&&kth<=nInputs));
                for(int o = 0; o < nInputs; o++){
                    System.out.print("Enter Input#: "+(o+1)+": ");
                    inputs[o] = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
                }
                for(int o = 0; o < nInputs; o++)
                    for(int i = o + 1; i < nInputs; i++)
                        if(inputs[o]<inputs[i]){
                temporarystorage = inputs[i];
                inputs[i] = inputs[o];
                inputs[o] = temporarystorage;
                        }
                System.out.println("Inputs in descending order: ");
                for(int i = 0; i < nInputs; i++)

                    System.out.print(inputs[i]+",");
                System.out.println("Kth position " + kth +" is "+inputs[kth-1]);


        }
    }
```

Comment: If it's sorted and you already output in descending order... you can just reverse the order in which you access the array. `for (int i = nInputs - 1; i >=0; i--)`

Comment: yikes! Crazy logic going on there, e.g. `!(kth>0&&kth<=nInputs)` instead of `kth<0 || kth>nInputs`

Comment: @RossDrew : My friend is the psycho when it comes to the logic part. I don't really get how he made it so god damn confusing lol.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
        if(inputs[o]<inputs[i]){
            temporarystorage = inputs[i];
            inputs[i] = inputs[o];
            inputs[o] = temporarystorage;
        }
```

to

```
        if(inputs[o]>inputs[i]){
            temporarystorage = inputs[i];
            inputs[i] = inputs[o];
            inputs[o] = temporarystorage;
        }
```

will sort it in ascending order.

Or if it is already sorted, just output it reversely as suggested by user1071777.